# Why does 7zip Ignore my InstallPath when making a SFX installer?

Tags: installation, config, 7zip, sfx

Currently, I am making a SFX with 7zip using the following config:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
InstallPath="C:\\test"
GUIMode="2"
RunProgram="7z465.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

I then package 7z465.exe into Setup.7z, and then call the following line in a batch file:

```
copy /b "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zSD.sfx" + config.txt + ".\Release\Setup.7z" .\Release\Setup.exe
```

When I run the resulting Setup.exe, It extracts fine and launches the 7z465.exe as well, but it is still extracting to some 7zip temp folder for the current user and not C:\test!

Running as administrator seems to have no effect either.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use modified 7zsd.sfx from http://7zsfx.solta.ru. InstallPath only works with the modified package.

Comment: Thanks! Marking this one instead of my own.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  This helped me get around some nastiness that my company's anti-virus program was causing my installer.

Comment: I had success with the 7zSD (7zsd_All.sfx) package from http://www.7zsfx.info/en/ as well, if the link above doesn't work.

Comment: (1/2) For people from the future: 7zsfx.solta.ru and 7zsfx.info are both gone. I've had some luck with archive.org's backups. The most recent working version I've found is `7zsd_All.sfx` in [this archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403000431/http://7zsfx.info/files/7zsd_extra_160_3873.7z). The rest of the archived file downloads are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://7zsfx.info:80/files/*), or you can browse an archived version of the site such as [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120213233851/http://7zsfx.info/en/). continued...

Comment: (2/2) Additionally, I found [this program](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-zipsfxbuilder/) pretty helpful for creating the configs, and it also comes packaged with some versions of the modified sfx files located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\7z SFX Builder\3rdParty\Modules` once you install it.

Answer (score 0):

I never found out why this was happening, and after hours of struggling with it, I switched to WinRAR. Granted, its got some quirks of its own, but I was at least able to figure those out and get it running for my needs.

Would recommend WinRAR over 7z for SFX stuff.

Comment: While I agree with you that WinRAR was much easier to get to work than 7zip, I downvoted this answer because it did not address the OP's original question.

Comment: but it was posted by the OP !

Comment: WinRAR is much easier to create SFX installers with. Note however that you must purchase a licence if you intend to distribute the installers commercially. See item 7 in the [WinRAR Licence](http://www.win-rar.com/winrarlicense.html): "There are no additional license fees, apart from the cost of the license, associated with the creation and distribution of RAR archives, volumes, self-extracting archives or self-extracting volumes."

Comment: Also downvoted bc it does not provide an code - just opinion.