# How to self-extract .jar file and auto run

Tags: java, jar, 7zip, self-extracting

I am wondering how I can self-extract a .jar file (and supporting files) then auto run the .jar file.

This would basically mean the application as a whole would run from the one click.

I have read and tried the 7zExtras but not had any luck so far. I get extraction failed Archive is corrupt.

Please note, this is not a self-extracting .jar file, but a .jar file inside a zipped folder that needs to be ran after extraction.

Comment: have you looked through the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904532/how-do-i-make-a-self-extract-and-running-installer

Comment: Its not the same but thanks anyway. The way I got it to work was by making the config file run a batch and the batch run the .jar file. Worked a treat although not pretty. I have read through the best answer on there and it didnt quite work as nicely but using the batch worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `jar` (MyProject.jar) file inside a `zip` (MyZipDir.zip).

If you run the command below, it works fine:

**`Java -cp MyZipDir.zip -jar bin/MyProject.jar`** -- Assuming jar is in bin dir of zip file.

Once it works, you can create .bat or .sh as per your operating system as such:

**MyRunner.bat**

```
@ECHO ON
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;MyZipDir.zip
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Xms128m -Xmx384m -jar bin/MyProject.jar
```