# How to create an executable file (or JAR) from a running program?

Tags: java, jar

I have a program and I would like it to create a JAR file. Obviously to create a text file you'd just use some `FileWriter` class, but what arguments would I pass to `.write()` if it isn't text? For example given the file `A.jar`, how could the program `B.class` actually write a copy of `A.jar` to the computer it's run on?

Basically I'm asking, how do installers work?

Comment: *how do installers work*, hmm, i'm confused between the title and the question inside.. However, if you ask us *how do installers work*, they **extract** the files they want to put into your computer from some sort storage (their own file - like a self extracting zip files, or external file) and do some registration (pre or post installation task which is pretty complex).

Comment: @BagusTesa how do they embed then extract the files?

Comment: it just a rough idea, i have not fiddled with executables lately.. they remembers the 'offset' or the location where the 'zip' is begin, and then runs the code that does the extraction. well, rather than going full blown playing with binary reading (and perhaps some sorcery, i mean assembly), you could use [7zip sfx module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896241/4648586)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jar file is just a zip file conforming to a specific set of rules.

You *can* use FileWriter but it is much easier to use the zip file classes. See [How to create a zip file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091788/53897) for a question about that.

Installers typically unzip a big file producing the various files the application needs (and create shortcuts etc.) You may want to play with launch4j to see how a commonly used installer works.