# How to execute an exe created with 7zip sfx with parameters

Tags: 7zip, sfx

We are in process of creating an self extract exe with help of 7zs.sfx, following instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904532/how-do-i-make-a-self-extract-and-running-installer)

Works well till this point, but we are unable to run the exe via command prompt that accepts command line arguments.

Example: Selfextract.exe arg1 arg2 arg3

There is an option to configure "ExecuteParameters" option in config.txt with hard coded parameters passed as arguments to an application configured with "ExecuteFile"

Example:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!

Title="Application v1.0.0.0"

ExecuteParameters="Argument"

ExecuteFile="Install.exe"

;!@InstallEnd@!
```

How to pass an argument through command line rather than hard coding the argument in config.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters could be passed to the self extract exe without any changes to config file.

Example: Selfextract.exe arg1 arg2 arg3

arg1, arg2 and arg3 parameters would be passed to the exe configured in config.txt by default.

Eventually considering the example, Install.exe is run with arg1, arg2 and arg3 parameters.