# Embed multiple cabinets with Wix v4

Tags: wix, windows-installer, cab

I have a MSI installer created with Wix v4 which has grown in size and now is bigger than 2GB. Now, it does not work any more because of it.

Indeed, Wix outputs the following warning:

```
warning WIX1158: The Windows Installer does not support Package files larger than 2GB in size.
```

And indeed, the installer fails with an error linked to that when attempting to run it.

When setting `EmbedCab` to `no` in `MediaTemplate` element, the .cab files are generated next to the MSI and must be distributed with the MSI file.

However, none of my .cab file is greater than 2GB (the biggest one is ~500MB), so I guess that when embedding them, they are embed as a single archive.

Is there any way, to prevent embedded .cab files to be more than 2GB (even by distributing files manually)? Or maybe a MSI can't be more than 2GB itself in general?

Otherwise, how could I bundle my MSI and the .cab files with some kind of wrapper?

My application is only for x64, so maybe there is some way to specify it to override the 2GB limitation?

Comment: I may have a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904532/how-do-i-make-a-self-extract-and-running-installer but this is more a tweak than anything else

Answer (score 0):

This:

> Or maybe a MSI can't be more than 2GB itself in general?

is another way to say this:

> The Windows Installer does not support Package files larger than 2GB in size.

So, it follows that:

> the installer fails with an error linked to that when attempting to run it.

Now, you can create a Bundle to wrap it all up in a single excitable, but note that a multi-GB executable launches very slowly (especially when signed).